# Facebook Login with React Native 0.49

Tags: node.js, reactjs, fbsdk, react-native-fbsdk

My setup is `React Native 0.49`, `Node 6.x` , `React 16` . I have configured my AVD with SDK Api 23 since react native has support only till the `Marshmallow` as of today.

I have installed `react-native-fbsdk` ver 4.22 and followed all the steps as per the official documentation. I am getting the below error.

I am guessing the `SDK` has failed to initialize

```
10 - 09 21:30:18.620 8098- 8115 / com.androidlogin E/ AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
Process: com.androidlogin, PID: 8098
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.Boolean.booleanValue()' on a null object reference
at com.facebook.FacebookSdk.getAutoLogAppEventsEnabled(FacebookSdk.java:858)
at com.facebook.appevents.internal.AutomaticAnalyticsLogger.logActivateAppEvent(AutomaticAnalyticsLogger.java:46)
at com.facebook.internal.FetchedAppSettingsManager$1.run(FetchedAppSettingsManager.java:132)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Answer (score 0):

If that is not working, try using the [PassportJS Facebook strategy](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-facebook).

Comment: @Seneca Thanks Seneca i do not want to add the extra Node.js complexity here  hence would like to go with the Facebook SDK for React Native. I missed specifying the error before the one mentioned above. I have also set the app id correctly in androidmanifest and referring to string.xml

Comment: I get the below error followed by the crash10-10 09:07:36.783 3609-3609/com.androidlogin I/FacebookInitProvider: Failed to auto initialize the Facebook SDK
                                                                      A valid Facebook app id must be set in the AndroidManifest.xml or set by calling FacebookSdk.setApplicationId before initializing the sdk.

Comment: --------- beginning of crash
10-10 09:07:39.805 3609-3623/com.androidlogin E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
                                                                Process: com.androidlogin, PID: 3609
                                                                java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.Boolean.b